# Disabled product variant still shows in {% for %} loop

Tags: templating, plugin-craftcommerce

Disabling a product variant doesn't remove it from a `{% for purchasable in product.variants %}` loop I have set up. It still renders an image associated with it, as well as a color swatch. Essentially not disabling it at all.

`{% for purchasable in product.variants if purchasable.status('live') %}` isn't working either, which I assume is only applicable to the product model.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should filter the variants by their enabled status:

```
{% set product = craft.commerce.products.id(productId).first() %}

{% for variant in product.variants if variant.enabled %}
    {{ variant.id }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It's always so simple, I feel so dumb for not even trying that! :)

Comment: On the other hand, you would think a disabled variant would be hidden by default unless included through templating.

Comment: I agree; you would think that `product.variants` would only return enabled products. How would you test to see if a product has enabled variants? Would you need to loop through and create a new array with only enabled variants? Or is there some property to access only enabled variants.

Comment: To get only enabled variants of a product you can do it like this: 

     `{% set variants = craft.commerce.variants({
                                    product: product,
                                    enabled: true
                                }) %}`