# Get only enabled variants of a product

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, variants

I would like to get all enabled variants for a product. I refer to the following question, where a method for limiting a for-loop is given:

[Disabled product variant still shows in {% for %} loop](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/21093/disabled-product-variant-still-shows-in-for-loop)

In the comments Andreas provides a way to get all enabled variants for a product:

{% set variants = craft.commerce.variants({ product: product, enabled: true }) %}

However, in my case this does not return any variants, while there are two active. Instead, it returns the following object:

```
object(craft\commerce\services\Variants)#2364 (3) {
  ["_events":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_eventWildcards":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_behaviors":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
  NULL
}
```

How can I get all the active variants for a product?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have the product

#### PHP

```php
$product = Product::find()->one();
$variants = ArrayHelper::filterByValue($product->variants, 'enabled', 1);
```

#### Twig

```twig
{% set product = craft.products.one() %}
{% set variants = product.variants|filterByValue('enabled', "1") %}
```

If you don't have the product

#### Twig

```twig
{% set variants = craft
    .commerce
    .variants
    .productId(x)
    .all() 
%}
```

#### PHP

```php
$variants = Variant::find()
    ->productId(x)
    ->all();
```